# FlexSlider2 not working

Tags: jquery, carousel, flexslider

I am totally new at jQuery stuff and would appreciate any help with my code. I downloaded the FlexSlider2 because I would like to make a gallery for a site I am working on. The gallery is currently not live so I cannot provide a link to it. I have put the code in that was provided and it just doesn't seem to work. I have no idea what I am doing wrong because I don't know enough about jQuery. Can someone please assist?

Here is what I have so far--oh and I have linked everything to my page and I am working in DreamWeaver. This part is in the "head" of my page

```
<link href="CustomerGallery/flex/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      // The slider being synced must be initialized first
      $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: false,
  slideshow: false,
  itemWidth: 210,
  itemMargin: 5,
  asNavFor: '#slider'
   {(;
$('#slider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  animationLoop: false,
  sync: "#carousel"
    {(;
{(;
   </script>
```

This part is in the "body" of my page

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="CustomerGallery/resources/images/medium/slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="CustomerGallery/resources/images/medium/slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="CustomerGallery/resources/images/medium/slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <div id="carousel" class="flexslider" style="margin-top:-50px">
                      <ul class="slides">

    <li>
      <img src="CustomerGallery/resources/images/thumb/slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="CustomerGallery/resources/images/thumb/slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="CustomerGallery/resources/images/thumb/slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you are able to provide!

Answer (score 0):

You have typo error:
Replace:

```
{(;
{(;
```

by:

```
});
});
```

just before `</script>`

And here too:

```
asNavFor: '#slider'
   {(;
```

should be:

```
asNavFor: '#slider'
   });
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Unfortunately after correcting those syntax errors-- it is still not working.

Comment: "it is still not working" doesn't really help to solve your problem... Have you got any errors in console?

Comment: ok looks like I have "div id" mark up somewhere else on the page for other code I am using. So I have changed both div's listed above to "classes"-- at least the photos are showing now (but in a list-- vertically), but now they are still not working as a slider.

Comment: Is there something in the CSS that I need to switch to make the script work?